# Access Query and VBA SQL returns different data for "Having"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query with the following SQL in the query editor:

```
SELECT tbl_PN_Import.PN, Last(tbl_PN_Import.Master_PN) AS Master_PN
FROM tbl_PN_Import
GROUP BY tbl_PN_Import.PN
Having (((Last(tbl_PN_Import.Master_PN)) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY tbl_PN_Import.PN;`
```

It returns 10,000+ records in query editor.

Below are a list of sample records. Our database contains master part numbers which have a one-to-many relationship with alternate part numbers.  The PN field contains all part numbers both master and alternates.  If a PN is a master PN it is has no entry in the Master_PN field.  If a PN is an alternate part number its Master_PN is in the Master_PN field.

```
PN                 Master_PN 
NAS1149FN432P 
AN960-4            NAS1149FN432P 
AD64ALS 
SSPQ-4-3 
SSPQ-04-03         SSPQ-4-3
```

When I run the query in VBA using a SQL string variable and `.OpenRecordSet`it only returns only the first record.  When I remove `Having....` it returns the expected 70,000+ records.

I have other queries without that do not have the `Having...` verb that work fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you replace `Last` by `Min` (or `Max`, depending), what happens?

Comment: @Tomalak: When I replace `Last` with `Min` or `Max` I get 70,000+ records.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of 10-15 records that show how your table looks like, and the result that you want to get from them (i.e. outline the effect you want to achieve with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`)?

Comment: @tomalak I've added sample records to the question.

Comment: A recordset is like a cursor. Unless you call the movenext, movelast methods you will of course be on the first row returned. And the recordcount method will not return the count of the entire recordset until you have called the movelast method (or have reached the end of the recordset).

Answer (score 1):

Try just to filter out *Null* values:

```sql
SELECT tbl_PN_Import.PN, Last(tbl_PN_Import.Master_PN) AS Master_PN
FROM tbl_PN_Import
WHERE tbl_PN_Import.Master_PN Is Not Null
GROUP BY tbl_PN_Import.PN
ORDER BY tbl_PN_Import.PN
```

or, as *Last* just returns "a value":

```sql
SELECT tbl_PN_Import.PN, Max(tbl_PN_Import.Master_PN) AS Master_PN
FROM tbl_PN_Import
WHERE tbl_PN_Import.Master_PN Is Not Null
GROUP BY tbl_PN_Import.PN
ORDER BY tbl_PN_Import.PN
```

Comment: Thanks for your SQL!  Your first SQL returns 10,435 records in the query editor.   This is same as my SQL in the query editor.  In VBA it returns 10,772 records....which turns out is the correct number.  Your second SQL returns 10,772 in both the query editor and VBA.  I would think that the query editor and the SQL engine in VBA would return the same result!

Comment: Can't tell. Both my queries will return those records where Master_PN is not null, thus the same record count. So, something else is going on. Double-check your data.

Answer (score 1):

`LAST` is not defined on an unsorted result set, which means any row is fine. Use a subquery to enforce a specific order, or avoid using `LAST` altogether.

An example of a subquery would be:

```
SELECT PN, Last(Master_PN) AS Master_PN
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_PN_Import ORDER BY Some_ID_field)
GROUP BY PN
Having Last(Master_PN) Is Not Null
ORDER BY tbl_PN_Import.PN;
```

If you don't have an ID field or anything you can order by, you can't expect `LAST` to produce coherent results.